# Emojis look different on Answer and Editing the Answer

Tags: support, bug, markdown-preview, unicode

In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49231913/6195472) answer, I used some numbers emojis (1 - 10) and only the last one (10) looks good. I tried to edit to see if I made something wrong, and surprisingly they look good on the Editing part.
I made a gif with the issue:

[image: gif with issue]

System details:
Google Chrome 65.0.3325.181
Mac OS X 10.11.6

Comment: I think this is due to the font. OSX replaces those unicode thingies.

Answer (score 3):

This is the fault of the code prettify, which converted the unicode characters to something else.

Since this isn't really code, code block should not be used.

Using `<pre>` tags works just fine, without trying to prettify the text.

Comment: It doesn't work on my end. The result is still the same.

Comment: @Patrick worked for me, did you check [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49225971/discord-js-message-react-fails-when-adding-specific-unicode-emotes/49231913#49231913) now?

Comment: Yes. On three browsers.

Comment: It looks fixed on my end, just weird that it didn't display on the answer, but did on the Edit screen

Comment: @Patrick weird. But question is, what you see in preview, when editing the post? That's what this bug report is about. So if in the preview you also don't see the characters, it's not related to this specific bug report.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPTIp.png

Comment: I see the same as linked in the edit window.

Comment: @AndréPaulo not weird, the prettify wasn't active when you edited.